# JOGL Snow Leopard and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, jogl

I'm trying to get JOGL running in Eclipse 3.5 on a MacbookPro 64bit Snow Leopard with Java 1.6. 
The code runs on my XP machine, however, when I try to run it on my macBook, I get this error in Eclipse's console:

> Invalid memory access of location 00000000 eip=8fe11f32

And thats it. 
I've tried a few different codes, and they all give me the same error msg.

Any ideas on what to try or where the problem may lie? 
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a total shot in the dark, I would guess that somewhere you've got a 32 bit library running on a 64 bit machine. I could easily imagine that some bit-twiddly optimized code runs right into null pointer territory when the size of the pointer is incorrect. Without knowing more, I would suggest making sure everything you're using is built for the right architecture.

Comment: This was it, thanks! 
The build that ended up working was jogl-1.1.1a-macosx-universal.zip

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the very latest video driver? Does it support OpenGL?